# How do I use PHPUnit with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, testing, phpunit

I would like to know how to write PHPUnit tests with Zend_Test and in general with PHP.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using Zend_Test to completely test all controllers. It's quite simple to set up, as you only have to set up your bootstrap file (the bootstrap file itself should NOT dispatch the front controller!). My base test-case class looks like this:

```
abstract class Controller_TestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap=array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        Zend_Auth::getInstance()->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_NonPersistent());
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
    }

    protected function appBootstrap()
    {
        Application::setup();
    }
}
```

where `Application::setup();` does all the setup up tasks which also set up the real application. A simple test then would look like this:

```
class Controller_IndexControllerTest extends Controller_TestCase
{
    public function testShowist()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/');
        $this->assertController('index');
        $this->assertAction('list');
        $this->assertQueryContentContains('ul li a', 'Test String');
    }
}
```

That's all...

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? I like your abstract TestCase class! Where do you put your Controller_TestCase? Do you need to require/include any files? How do you run a test? Do you use PHPUnit via the command line, or with a plugin in an IDE? Thanks!

Comment: I put Controller_TestCase in my tests/Controller directory - that's the directory where all controller test cases are located. Generally I don't use auto-loading when running unit-tests but if I do controller tests, I use Zend_Loader::registerAutoload() to use auto-loading because it's very...

Comment: ... difficult to track dependencies with the MVC running. You just have to make sure that you follow the naming convention and that Zend_Loader will find your files (set include_path).
To run my tests I use the CLI of PHPUnit because I don't like the PHPUnit integration in Eclipse PDT. It's...

Comment: ... actually no problem to switch windows to start the tests - especially if you follow the PHPUnit naming convention (the same as Zend Framework's convention) and use TestSuites to group your tests.
Perhaps you should have a look at the testing structure used by e.g. the Zend Framework itself.

Answer (score 7):

They have an "[Introduction to the Art of Unit Testing](http://devzone.zend.com/1115/an-introduction-to-the-art-of-unit-testing-in-php/)" on the Zend Developer Zone, which covers PHPUnit.

Comment: link is currently broken

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/190-Setting-up-your-Zend_Test-test-suites.html) article very useful. Also [Zend_Test](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.html) documentation helped a lot.
With the help of these two resources, I managed to succesfully implement unit testing in the [QuickStart tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) of the Zend Framework and write few tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using ZF 1.10, I put some bootstrap code into tests/bootstrap.php (basically what is in (public/index.php), until $application->bootstrap().

Then I am able to run a test using

```
phpunit --bootstrap ../bootstrap.php  PersonControllerTest.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Zend_Test but I have written tests against apps using Zend_MVC and the like.  The biggest part is getting enough of your bootstrap code in your test setup.

Answer (score 0):

Plus if you using a database transaction then it would be best to delete all the transaction that is gets done via a unit test otherwise your database gets all messed.

so on set up

```
public function setUp() {



    YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->setUnitTestMode(true);



    YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->query("BEGIN");

    YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->getCache()->clear();

    // Manually Start a Doctrine Transaction so we can roll it back
    Doctrine_Manager::connection()->beginTransaction();
}
```

and on teardown all you need to do is rollback

```
public function tearDown() {



    // Rollback Doctrine Transactions
    while (Doctrine_Manager::connection()->getTransactionLevel() > 0) {
        Doctrine_Manager::connection()->rollback();
    }

    Doctrine_Manager::connection()->clear();



    YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->query("ROLLBACK");
    while (YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->getTransactionDepth() > 0) {
        YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->rollback();
    }
    YOUR_ZEND_DB_INSTANCE::getInstance()->setUnitTestMode(false);

}
```